# Boto3 upload core dumping Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

How do you diagnose the Python Boto3 API causing Python to crash with a core dump?

I'm trying to use the [Django-Bakery](https://django-bakery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to upload some static webpages to an S3 bucket using it's `manage.py publish` command.

It appears to run fine for a few seconds, but when it tries to issue s3.PutObject commands, the process crashes with the error:

```
[2020-04-12 11:28:18] botocore.hooks DEBUG Event needs-retry.s3.PutObject: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f92cb7ed2e8>
[2020-04-12 11:28:18] botocore.retryhandler DEBUG No retry needed.
[2020-04-12 11:28:18] botocore.hooks DEBUG Event needs-retry.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f92cb7ed2b0>>
[2020-04-12 11:28:18] s3transfer.utils DEBUG Releasing acquire 0/None
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This has been working fine without issue for months, so I'm not sure what's changed that might be causing this. I haven't changed any version numbers. The only thing I can think of is maybe one of my static files is structured in some way that's too much for the command to handle, but I'm not sure how to identify it. How do I fix this?

Comment: boto3 is pure python and pure python shouldn't be able to cause a segfault. Perhaps a native extension that boto3 pulls in? Have you tried inspecting the backtrace of the core file?

Comment: @jordanm Good point. Even pure Python can cause a segfault if it exploits a bug in the interpreter, but admittedly that's rare. I did notice my installed version of boto3 is a couple versions behind, so I'll simply try upgrading to the recent release in PyPI and see if that does anything.

Answer (score 0):

what I found might be slightly related to your question. I used aws cli to copy files from AWS EFS to S3 using Fargate, and it had weird behavior with big files(~5GB). The task was hung on the line

```
s3transfer.utils DEBUG Releasing acquire 0/None
```

I added `--only-show-errors` and `--no-progress` params and it helped, but I can not explain **why** it works that way :)

Comment: if you can't explain it how it is an answer ?

Comment: I shared what worked for me. Maybe it will help the question author or at least gives some ideas on what to check next.